# displaying data from Mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have data in my mySql database , the table structure  is as follows ,

```
   e_id | p_name | time | taskdate
   VT01 |   p1   | 2    | 2013-11-22
   VT01 |   p1   |  1   | 2013-11-23
   VT02 |   P2   |  3   | 2013-11-23
   VT01 |   P3   |  2   | 2013-11-24
```

E_id are for different employees . User enters the employee id , and based on that id , i should pull the data from mysql and display it in following fashion . I have a week select , which selects a week . Eg. employee VT01 is selected and a week is selected

```
    P_name | S | M | TU | W | TH | F | S
      P1   | 2 | 1 |    |   |    |   |  
      P2   |   |   | 2  |   |    |   |
```

how should my query to database should be and how to display it in php

Comment: How do **you** think it should be?

Comment: Have you tried to write a query? What do you mean with the week select? Is that the taskdate? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: yup thats the taskdate as dayofweek(taskdate)

Comment: No, this requires a fairly complicated query. Including a cross tab. It's a valid question. I'm writing the answer.

Comment: Yea thankx Jasny . :) waiting for your answer , i am basically creating a timesheet

Answer (score 1):

- First use [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to get the specific day of the week.
- Next you should group by p_name.
- Last next you want to create what is called a [cross tab](http://www.jasny.net/articles/creating-a-cross-tab-in-mysql/).

All together you'll get

```
SELECT
  p_name,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 1, `time`, 0)) AS `su`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 2, `time`, 0)) AS `mo`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 3, `time`, 0)) AS `tu`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 4, `time`, 0)) AS `we`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 5, `time`, 0)) AS `th`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 6, `time`, 0)) AS `fr`,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(taskdate) = 7, `time`, 0)) AS `sa`
FROM mytable
WHERE e_id = 'VT01'
GROUP BY p_name WITH ROLLUP
```

### [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28699/4)

Comment: Thanx JASNY , appreciate your help , i will try it out bro

Comment: hey Jasny , need one more help , i extracted the data , i also want a last coloumn to be total , which sums all vallue under a day , supoose time spent in monday

Comment: Just add [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to the `GROUP BY`. I modified the answer.

Comment: If you're helped, please **accept the answer** (checkmark at right of the answer) and upvote (arrow up). Thanks :)

Comment: one more question please help , my deadline is today , i am creating a grid like timesheet , i extract the data as you said in text boxes of table ,i want to allow user to update those places where time is 0 in database , like i want to update time where date='something ' and p_name ='something ' . Please help , would be very grateful

Comment: OR how to write the same query in mysqli , i can use editable grid jquery plugin ...any way i need to create a timesheet which can update mysql from the table itself

Comment: That's an entirely new problem. Please post a new question with code code you already have.

Comment: hey i cant as i coudnt create new questions , if possible gimme your email_id , i will send u the details , i need it to be done today , job at stake , please help me dude

Comment: please jasny help me out